# Running .bat in current cmd.exe from java application

Tags: java

I've got a simple batch file:

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
echo "Hello World!"
```

And I would like to run a java application that runs that batch file in the same `cmd.exe` process. An example of this would look like:

```
> java -jar my.jar
Hello World!
```

This is a trivial case, as the real batch file I plan to use will require users to input at certain times, thus I need the batch file to be *running*, not just a printable like the example shown.

I've tried the following without success:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./my.bat");
// and
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./my/bat");
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitfor();
```

Is this doable? I don't want to open another `cmd.exe`, thus my `exec()` arguments are not:

`'cmd /k start ./my.bat'`

Which would open a new window.

My project structure:

```
root
-- my.jar
-- src
---- ...
-- manifest.mf
-- my.bat
```

So when I issue:

```
> my.bat
"Hello World!"

> java -jar my.jar
// nothing appears
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not practically possible to run a batch file in the cmd.exe process that launched your Java process. This is because the cmd.exe process is currently doing the equivalent of Java's `Process.waitFor()` while it's waiting for your Java process to finish.

But maybe what you really want is not necessarily to run a batch file in the same *process* as the Java application's parent process, but just the same *window*. To do that, use [ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("my.bat");
pb.inheritIO();
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitfor();
```

The `inheritIO()` call causes the batch file's output to appear in your Java process's System.out, and your Java process's System.in to link to your batch file's input.

Comment: Right on the money! Excellent solution. I wanted the batch to appear in the same window.